# How to display special characters in your application?

Tags: android, textview, special-characters

Hi I want to ask if it is possible to put/display index character in textview.settext. I want to display CO2 but I want the number 2 to be displayed as an index number (such as in a real chemical formula.

Comment: Try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can try below code.

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("CO<sup>2</sup>"));
```

or for subscript you can try it like below.

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("CO<sub>2</sub>"));
```

Hope this is gonna help you.

Comment: haha this did the trick. Well sort of the number is now high up not down below

Comment: which one you used `CO<sup>2</sup>` or `CO<sub>2</sub>`

Comment: ops sorry didn't see the difference between "suP" and "suB" so yeah  with suP the number 2 is going UP with suB is going down but if it goes up or down it is "cut" in half by the line size I guess. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Use `CO<sub>2</sub>` instead of `CO<sup>2</sup>` and it will show you below of the text... And please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: yeah sure but the number 2 is cut in half how can I fix this?

Comment: I think your Text-view's height is not set enough that's why it is cutting half, make sure your text-view's height is big and it will show full.

Comment: Yep you are right just finished testing it myself everything is fine thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Pleasure is all mine. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 3):

Since above answers would be enough for writing the sub index in the formula CO2, they don't answer the generic question , which is displaying special characters.

The problem is that the charset of android fonts do not contain some special characters. This is the [Android Character Set](http://www.ascendercorp.com/pdf/Droid_fonts.pdf)

One thing you can try, is to use another Font which contains the characters you want to use. This is the code to load a ttf font and use it in your TextView:

```
Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/font_name.ttf");
your_textview.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Your fonts should be placed in assets/fonts folder (create it if don't exist)

Answer (score 0):

There are supposed to be covered in UTF8 format; I think what you need to look for is Subscript and Superscript.